# Angular router.navigate does not navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I seem to be not the only one with this problem but can not find an answer.
So the problem is quite simple. I have an Angular application with a login form, when you press the login button, the following code is triggered (within the `LoginComponent`).

```
let self = this; // otherwise out of scope in catch(error);
this.authService.login(email, password).then(function (c) {
     console.log("Login succeeded")
     self.router.navigate(['/manage']);
   }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log("Login failed");
     self.error = error['message'];
});
```

Login succeeds, but the browsers stays on the `http://localhost:4200/login` page. Manually navigating to `http://localhost:4200/manage` does go the correct manage page. Going immediately to the `/manage` url manually before logging in redirects to my login page, so everything works with routing when typing in the address manually. I tried `self.router.navigate` with a lot of different parameters: `['manage']`, `['manage/']`, `['../manage']` etc

This is how my routing is organised in the `app-routing.module` class

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ManageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'manage', component: ManageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The `AuthGuard` implementation

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: AuthenticationService, public router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      if (!this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: forgot to mention probably importent detail: when `this.router.navigate['manage']` is called, the loginComponent (i.e. the login form) disappears, leaving me a blank page, but the url sill states `localhost:4200/login`.

Comment: It is probably about the AuthGuard but can't really tell as it's implementation is missing, Do you receive any errors? Also I'll recommend deleting the JS part from title since AngularJS indicates version 1.x whereas 2 and above is referred as just Angular.

Comment: Also you do not need the old school this = that, just use an arrow function instead.

Comment: I added the `AuthGuard` implementation. And yes, that single piece of code was the only place where I still used the old `function(x){}` syntax

Comment: and weirdly enough, when going to the `manage` url without being logged in, the `authGuard` works like a charm by navigating me to `/login`. But the exact same code (but with `'login'` replaced with `'manage'`) in `LoginComponent` does not.

Comment: Probably isAuthenticated still returns false, by the time you are trying to navigate, but again service source code is missing :)

Comment: Can you check if there are errors in the chrome console (F12)? The behavoor makes me think that the route simply doesn't exist. (Screenshot van de console is voldoende)

Comment: Angular's default behavior is not to navigate to an already loaded component, but you can get around it.  Maybe this will help. https://dev.to/jwp/angular-s-naviation-challenges-20i2

Comment: @Pieterjan, de route bestaat want manueel naar de url surfen werkt zoals verwacht. Het is puur de `.navigate['manage']` in de `loginComponent`. Probleem bleek te zijn bij een initialisatie van Google's `Firebase`, maar dat zou eingelijk niet mogen invloed hebben op de router